# Как заставить работать js в модальном окне Bootstrap?

Tags: graphics, bootstrap, javascript

Суть такая, что в модальном окне Bootstrap должен выводится график с помощью morris.js

Но вот незадача, на отдельной странице с графиком все ок, а в модальном окне все точки сбиваются в кучу.

Может кто чего посдкажет.

Проблема та же что и здесь http://toster.ru/q/62376

Comment: таксс... щас подумаем... Аго вон там у тебя в строке ХХ ошибка - нада вот 'это' поменять на 'ЭТО')

Comment: скорее уж на this